# What is the way to call variables in one file to another file in UNIX shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I have a .KSH file in which i have two variables Var1,Var2 what is the way to assign X,Y values in present in different file to Var1,Var2(Var1=x,Var2=y)

```
if      [ $STATUS != 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR - Failed to execute the BTEQ Script for abcd `date` " | mailx -s "Failed in Script xxxxx.ksh...!!!" $LIST1(first set of emails )
    return $STATUS
fi
echo "Completed load process for abcd  `date`" | mailx -s "Completed load process for abcd  `date`" -a $TGT_DIR/$FILE_NM $LIST2(second set of emails)
```

What is the best way to call this Two set's of emails from different file(either .txt or .ksh ) to my xxxxx.ksh script

Comment: I think you need to *"dot"* it in... `. otherFile.ksh`

Comment: what is the format of the second file ?  can you post an example ?

Comment: if      [ $STATUS != 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR - Failed to execute the BTEQ Script for abcd `date` " | mailx -s "Failed in Script xxxxx.ksh...!!!" $LIST1(first set of emails )
    return $STATUS
fi
echo "Completed load process for abcd  `date`" | mailx -s "Completed load process for abcd  `date`" -a $TGT_DIR/$FILE_NM $LIST2(second set of emails)


so would like to create a file with this set of emails and call in my xxxxx.ksh file 
what is the better way to do it

Comment: Could you edit the question and fix the markup, please? I gave it a go but failed to understand the relevance from `if [ $STATUS != 0 ] then echo` and onwards.

Comment: As an aside, your `if` has a bug -- if `STATUS=''`, then this would just run `if [ != 0 ]`, which isn't valid syntax. If you quote your expansions, as in `[ "$STATUS" != 0 ]`, then you don't have that problem. See http://shellcheck.net/, which will catch that kind of bug automatically.

Comment: On a different note, all-caps variable names are actually [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) for names with meaning to the shell or system, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. Consider putting your names in that space to ensure you won't overwrite important names by mistake (since setting a shell variable with the same name as an environment variable will overwrite the latter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a common file in our TTU server's bash scripts (where we execute our bteq and tpt), although this is not specific to TTU, but rather any linux shell script.

For common variables we have a single file `variables.ksh` that takes the format:

```
export LIST1="name@domain.com name2@domain.com name3@domain.com"
export LIST2="name4@domain.com name5@domain.com"
export ETLLogon="someusername"
export WorkDatabase="Commonlyusedb"
export othervariables="other values"
```

Then in each shell script that needs to utilize these, you just bring it in with a `.`:

```
#!/bin/ksh

#import common variables
. /path/to/variables.ksh

#and now you can use these:
if      [ $STATUS != 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR - Failed to execute the BTEQ Script for abcd `date` " | mailx -s "Failed in Script xxxxx.ksh...!!!" $LIST1
    return $STATUS
fi
echo "Completed load process for abcd  `date`" | mailx -s "Completed load process for abcd  `date`" -a $TGT_DIR/$FILE_NM $LIST2
```

There's no need in this scenario to EXPORT the variables but we often drop to subshells in our scripts, so it's handy.

Comment: Strings, rather than native arrays, for lists?

Comment: Well... Technically with Teradata (ttu is the etl suite) I generally store my email lists in the database when they aren't hard coded in whatever script and then pull them out via BTEQ when needed.